# parameter of passing cookie

Tags: java, web-applications, browser

Do a browser pass the cookie name and cookie value saperately or both in one string ? Do it also pass domain or not??? I want to know what happens in the case of a java browser.

Comment: Cookie is passed as one string (unfortunately). Domain is passed in recent (ie 99%) browsers. A Java browser... a browser written in Java... a browser visiting a JSP.../Tomcat page...? For the record one '?' is enough to have SO helpers understand it is a question.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are sent as HTTP header, which is a pair of strings.

What kind of java browser are you talking about?

If you want to make a HTTP request in java, I'd suggest you use [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html).